# Compact set example

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can you please give me an example of a set that is closed but not compact in R^2\Bbb? I know that a compact set is the one that is closed and bounded, and the set [a,b] is compact. But this question does not make sense to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you need something that's closed, but not bounded.  What are some non-bounded sets that come to mind?

Comment: R^n is not bounded for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** $X$ is always a closed subset of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Put a closed and not bounded set : $\mathbb R^2$ it's self for example is closed but not compact. An other example :$[0,1] \times [0,+\infty[$